# Using Vertica parameters in SSIS

Tags: parameters, ssis, vertica

I have a query that pulls a set of data based on START DATE and END DATA parameter used in Vertica.

Here is the filter in the vertica query:

> where list.transaction_date between :start_date and :end_date

How do i handle this in the "SQL command text:" box for an SSIS ODBC Connection?

Comment: Have you tried the ADO.NET driver? That's how I got it to work in SSRS.

Comment: I have to use a ODBC driver for Vertica. You were able to connect to vertica using the ADO.NET driver?

Comment: I could only use parameters with SSRS using the ADO.NET driver, with a caveat (parameters only supported in queries consisting of one statement). Did not try SSIS though.

Answer (score 0):

With an ODBC driver, you indicate parameters with `?` which is a one-based ordinal system https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms140355(v=sql.110)

Your filer would become something like

```
where list.transaction_date between ? and ?
```

And then in the Parameter tab of the Execute SQL Task or click the Parameter button in the ODBC Source and connect parameter name 1 to @[User::MyStartDate] and parameter name 2 to @[User::MyEndDate]

This assumes that you have two SSIS variables called MyStartDate and MyEndDate. The $64k question is: what data type should that be? I have no idea. Best case scenario, you can use the Date/Datetime data type in SSIS and the ODBC driver can translate formats between the two. Less good case is that your variables become strings and you have to manipulate them into allowable values for Vertica.

Absolute worst case is that you can't parameterize in the tooling and you instead need to build a dynamic string, via expressions, with Vertica compliant values and syntax.

Comment: yea, i tried that and i got the below error message:

Comment: state: '42601'. Native Error Code: 4856. ERROR 4856:  Syntax error at or near "and" at character 9312
                                                                                                                                         For a vertica query , how do i set the variable? both dates are DATE format. Thanks for your help!